# How to print the number of failures for every test case using SoftAssert in TestNG

Tags: testing, testng, assert, assertions, assertion

I have a test case that performs the following:

```
@Test
public void testNumber() {
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    List<Integer> nums  = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    for (Integer num : nums){
        softAssert.assertTrue(num%2==0, String.format("\n Old num : %d", num);
    }
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

The above test will fail for numbers 1,3,5,7,9
Five statements will be printed in the test report.

If I run the test for a larger data set, I find it difficult to get the count of test data that failed the test case.

Is there any easier way to get the number of test data that failed for a test case using softAssert itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to find count of test data that failed the test case in SoftAssert itself is not possible.

Alternatively you can think of extending **Assertion** class. Below is the sample that gives **count of test data that failed the test case** and prints each failure in new line.

```
package yourpackage;

import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
import org.testng.asserts.IAssert;
import org.testng.collections.Maps;

public class AssertionExtn extends Assertion {

private final Map<AssertionError, IAssert> m_errors;

public AssertionExtn(){
    this.m_errors = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
}

protected void doAssert(IAssert a) {
    onBeforeAssert(a);
    try {
        a.doAssert();
        onAssertSuccess(a);
    } catch (AssertionError ex) {
        onAssertFailure(a, ex);
        this.m_errors.put(ex, a);
    } finally {
        onAfterAssert(a);
    }
}

public void assertAll() {
    if (!(this.m_errors.isEmpty())) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Total assertion failed: "+m_errors.size());
        sb.append("\n\t");
        sb.append("The following asserts failed:");
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry ae : this.m_errors.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append("\n\t");
            sb.append(((AssertionError)ae.getKey()).getMessage());
        }
        throw new AssertionError(sb.toString());
    }
}
}
```

You can use this as:

```
 @Test
    public void test()
    {
        AssertionExtn asert=new AssertionExtn();
        asert.assertEquals(false, true,"failed");
        asert.assertEquals(false, false,"passed");
        asert.assertEquals(0, 1,"brokedown");
        asert.assertAll();
    }
```